# MYSQL UPDATE COLUMN OF SAME TABLE WITH CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this, actually i need to update the superior column with id instead of name

by using mysql UPDATE query

The actual table

```
ID   |  USERNAME  |  SUPERVISOR_USERNAME  |  SUPERIOR  
1    |  jdoe      |  jsmith               | NULL   
2    |  jsmith    |  dduck                | NULL    
3    |  ANU       |  jsmith               | jdoe  
4    |  JOHN      |  dduck                | jdoe
5   |  NIKHIL     |  jsmith               | jsmith
6   |  JOSE       |  dduck                | jsmith
```

Expected result table

```
ID   |  USERNAME  |  SUPERVISOR_USERNAME  |  SUPERIOR    
1    |  jdoe      |  jsmith               | NULL    
2    |  jsmith    |  dduck                | NULL   
3    |  ANU       |  jsmith               | 1    
4    |  JOHN      |  dduck                | 1    
5   |  NIKHIL     |  jsmith               | 2    
6   |  JOSE       |  dduck                | 2
```

Comment: It is a bit strange that you want to use a varchar column to store numeric data.  You might want to just create a new column.

Comment: It's a simple join. You can manage that, right?

Answer (score 6):

Use an update with a self-join:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.SUPERIOR = t2.USERNAME
SET t1.SUPERIOR = t2.ID
```

Note that this update will not touch records having a `NULL` superior, but this should be acceptable as these records remain `NULL` in your expected output.

Comment: I believe OP wants an `UPDATE` query and not `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

Try warapping the `SELECT` query into an alias, e.g.:

```
UPDATE users t,
(SELECT id, username FROM users) t2
SET t.superior = t2.id
WHERE t.superior = t2.username;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e23e9/1/0)**.

Comment: its showing  #1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Muhammadali I have just updated the answer, try now?

Comment: I would expect an update join to be faster than a subquery approach, in general.

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
update your_table
set SUPERIOR = value 
where ID = YOUR_ID
```

This will work for you